# Image and text on one line with text (but text moved a bit up)

Tags: html, css, css-position

I have to implement the next thing.

[image: What]

An image and a text should be pinned down to bottom. Also they should be on one line, but a text should be 10px up relative to an image. It's all ok (because `img` tag has `display: inline` property), but I can't deal with this text stuff.

If I place a text in a div with `position: absolute; bottom: 0`, it'll overlap an image. If I make it `position: relative; float: left;`, it won't be pinned to the bottom of the block. Also I can't make it `position: absolute` with the `left` property set to the width of an image, because it can vary.

I can't even make a correct search request to find what I need. What can be done there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are several ways to do that. 
if it's really a text, try to apply css:

```
.text{line-height:200px}
/*you can adjust the line-hight to best suit your needs (100px or whatever)*/
```

you can also apply style="display:inline-block" to the text, that'll allow you to use margins and paddings (e.g. margin-bottom:10px \ padding-bottom:10px etc.) please, note, that  for cross browser (incl. old IEs) display:inline-block you should write something like this:

```
.text{
display: -moz-inline-stack;
display: inline-block;
zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

*the first line is for the old mozilla, matter of taste, it can be ommited.
zoom:1 and *display:inline is for old IEs (like 7 or 8)... it's not quite valid markup, but works perfect, so, no worries

Comment: Your and @user2320601 's code both worked (except that thing that no one of you told that *[I think there must be more `that` in this sentence]* an `img` tag there should have `float: left` to prevent overlapping by text), but mark goes to you because of the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```
    body, p, div{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    }
    div{
        position:relative;
        background:blue;
    }
    img{
        background:red;
        display:inline;
        width:200px;
        height:200px;
        margin-right:20px;

    }
    p{
        display:inline;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:10px;
    } 



    <body>
      <div id='x'>
        <img src='image'/>
        <p> Text </p>
      </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use absolute positioning, and try adding below css to the text

```
vertical-align: top;
```

Find the difference between [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/6nFEN/1/) and [**JSFiddle2**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/6nFEN/2/)

Comment: How this'll help me to move a text 10px up saving an image positioning?

Comment: @efpies couldn't get you, can you add a fiddle like I have? or you want to have the text in middle?

Comment: @efpies got you. may this help you(`vertical-align: bottom;`) You want both to be in same line.  Can you share the link?

Comment: Yes, I need them on the same line BUT text should be 10px up from this line. In other words, I should shift the baseline of text. I updated the picture in the post, take a look.